# How to make string comparison inclusive?

Tags: java

I have a TreeMap that contains words and its definition(s). I'm writing a method that will return all the word and its definitions with a range; it takes in two parameters: `string begin` and `string end`.
Here's what I have so far
I initialized a TreeMap outside of the function:

```
Map<String, List<String>> wordDictionary = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
```

```
Set<String> wordSet = wordDictionary.keySet();
    Iterator<String> iterator = wordSet.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      String current = iterator.next();
      if (
        (current.compareToIgnoreCase(begin) >= 0) &&
        (current.compareToIgnoreCase(end) <= 0)
      ) {
        List<String> defList = wordDictionary.get(current);
        System.out.println(current);
        Iterator<String> itr2 = defList.iterator();
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
          System.out.println(" " + itr2.next());
        }
      }
    }
```

Example use: "List a b"
The method should return all words from `a` to `b` 
However my method returns all words between `a` and `b`; it excludes words starting with `a` and `b`.

I tried tweaking the if case to

```
if (
        (current.compareToIgnoreCase(begin) > 0) &&
        (current.compareToIgnoreCase(end) < 0)
      )
```

but that doesn't work either. It displays words starting with `begin` but not `end`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Does "from `a` to `b`" mean that you want `a`, `ace`, `axe`, but not `b`, `bee`? Or does it mean you want `a`, `ace`, `axe`, `b`, `bee`, but not `c`, `car`?

Comment: You're never going to get the word "bee" when end is set to "b", since "bee" is greater than "b".

Comment: I don't see how the original code (using >= 0 for begin) could (1) exclude words starting with "a", nor (2) display fewer words than the modified code (using >) because by simple definition it includes more matching values.

Comment: @user13784117 In plain terms, "from K to P" means all words starting with `K` up to and *including* all words starting with `P`, which as a predicate would be written `s >= 'K' and s < 'Q'`. That's why I was asking for clarification, because "from A to B" meaning all A-words and just B, but not all the other B-words, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Andreas, your latter example is correct. For the command "List a b" would mean list all the words and its definitions from `a` to `b`. So in your example it would only be `a`, `ace`, `axe`, `b` ,  and `bee`

Comment: @Andreas - I agree, I was just getting to the same point by a different route.  So the appropriate change to the code is to have 'end' be the first word you don't want (which is consistent with general Java treatment of ranges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the subMap of TreeMap inclusive on both ends by doing something like the following:

```
TreeMap<String,String> map = new TreeMap<>();
         
map.put("abc","a");     
map.put("efg","a");      
map.put("hij","v");      
map.put("rst","o");

String start = "a";
String end = "e";

int idx = end.length() - 1;

// modify last character of end to be inclusive.
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end);
 char c = sb.charAt(sb.length()-1);
 sb.setCharAt(sb.length()-1, (char)(c+1));
 end = sb.toString();

Map<String, String> words =
        map.subMap(start, true, end,false);

System.out.println(words);
```

Prints

```
{abc=a, efg=a}
```

It increments the last character of the ending string so as to include anything less than that.

Comment: Since you're doing `end.length()`, you coded for `end` being more than one character long, but if that's so, you'd need `end.substring(0, end.length() - 1) +` in front, so that `"ego"` becomes `"egp"`, and you'd also need to specify `false` for upper-exclusive.

Comment: @Andreas You're right! Thanks for that. I would have surely missed it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a TreeMap, use its [`subMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap(K,boolean,K,boolean)) method!

```
Map<String, List<String>> range = wordDictionary.subMap(begin, true, end, true);
```

And iterate over the whole map.

The 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> parameters control if the range ends are inclusive or not - it seems you want inclusive both ends, but if not change the 4<sup>th</sup> parameter to `false`.

——

By the way, since you are not printing the word, just the definitions, your code can be reduced to:

```
wordDictionary.subMap(begin, true, end, true).values().stream()
.flatMap(List::stream)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you wanted to also print the word before indented definitions:

```
wordDictionary.subMap(begin, true, end, true).entrySet().stream()
.peek(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey()))
.map(Map.Entry::getValue)
.flatMap(List::stream)
.forEach(d -> System.out. println(" " + d);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to specify I do want to display the word too. For instance, "cat : " (new line) then the list of definition(s). There might be more than 1 definition

Comment: I'm getting an error `The method subMap(String, boolean, String, boolean) is undefined for the type Map<String,List<String>>` I'm looking into it. Thanks!

Comment: @C0DeX that’s because you have *declared*  `wordDictionary` as being a `Map`. Instead, change it to `TreeMap wordDictionary = ...`

Answer (score 2):

To get all keys that start with e.g. `'b'`, use [`subMap(K fromKey, boolean fromInclusive, K toKey, boolean toInclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-):

```java
TreeMap<String, String> wordDictionary = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
wordDictionary.put("A", "1");
wordDictionary.put("Abc", "2");
wordDictionary.put("Axe", "3");
wordDictionary.put("B", "4");
wordDictionary.put("Bee", "5");
wordDictionary.put("C", "6");
wordDictionary.put("Car", "7");

NavigableMap<String, String> bdict = wordDictionary.subMap("b", true, "c", false);
System.out.println(bdict);
System.out.println(bdict.keySet());

// Alternative
NavigableSet<String> bwords = wordDictionary.navigableKeySet().subSet("b", true, "c", false);
System.out.println(bwords);
```

*Output*

```
{B=4, Bee=5}
[B, Bee]
[B, Bee]
```